# c# datagridview doubleclick load data into seperate form

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

[image]Hi I have a main form which displays customer details. I created a separate form to search for a specific customer. On the doubleclick event I would like the data to be loaded into some textboxes in the main form and close I have tried several things through this website but had no luck..

I created this function in the mainform to load the data however I don't know how to call the function from the 'searchform' and also pass the selected row into the SQL query :

```
private void searchSelected()
    {
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from tbl_customers where custId = '" + custIdTxt.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                custIdTxt.Text = (dr["custId"].ToString());
                custRefTxt.Text = (dr["custRef"].ToString());
                nameTxt.Text = (dr["name"].ToString());
                contactTxt.Text = (dr["contact"].ToString());
                telephoneTxt.Text = (dr["telephone"].ToString());

            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Below is the double click function when the user selects the customer they wish to view the details off:

```
private void searchResults_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create `mainform` variable on `searchform`

```
MainForm mainform;
```

And then on `main form` before opening `searchform` write this to assign mainform

```
searchform srcform= new searchform();
srcform.mainform = this;
srcform.ShowDialog();
```

and then in double click event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgse)
{
     if(e.RowIndex > -1)
     {
          var row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
          searchSelected(Convert.ToInt32(row["custId"].ToString()));
     }
 }
```

Change `searchSelected`  method like this

```
private void searchSelected(int custId)
    {
        {
            //codes
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from tbl_customers where custId = '" + custId   + "'";
            //codes
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks however I think we got mixed up - i attached a screenshot to help you understand my exact problem.

Comment: Just move searchSelected method to searchform. It will solve your problem

Comment: No luck. Is there a way of calling a function in the main form on the double click. Then I would just send the string across and run the query

Comment: Keep getting the error mainform is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: You can set public main form, or you can call the main form function from child with Custom events